# Getting data from vSphere client

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vmware-workstation, node-vsphere

We would like to gather data from vSphere, metrics like number of servers, their names, traffic information (this to be defined later). What would be the best place to start and what steps do we need to accomplish this? Any brainstorming suggestions, SDKs etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by taking a look at the [vSphere Web Services](https://code.vmware.com/apis/968) API service and, more specifically, the HostSystem (ESXi hosts), VirtualMachine (VM), and PerformanceManager (source of metrics) managed objects.

SDK-wise, it really depends on your language of choice. The [vSphere Management SDK](https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/7.0/vsphere-management) includes several different languages including Java and .NET. There's also the open source "*vmomi" SDKs, for which there is Python (pyvmomi), Go (govmomi), and Ruby (rbvmomi).

Comment: Is the .NET SDK not deprecated or out of support?

Comment: It's supported under a level known as "SDK Support", which is the same for the rest of the above SDKs

Comment: Do you have a link? The one I found is deprecated https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/7.0/vsphere-automation-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

You can use VMware Orchestrator (vRO). Your vCenter license should cover this product. vRO uses the vCenter-SDK and also the vAPI. Big community and same vendor, so no (or very low) update issues.